# Table 1 and Table 2 have matching columns. How do I join the 9th column from table 2 to table 1 based on the matches?

Tags: postgresql

My Issue:

```
I want to know if an account has an active error.
```

Background Information:

I have 2 tables: 
    (1) Work - 9 Columns; 
    (2) Errors - 9 Columns

The Work table contains Account Numbers and 8 variables which are associated to an error from the Errors table.

The Errors table contains each possible error. Each error has 8 variables and is either set as on (y) or off (n) with an Active Flag column.

```
    In table 1 (Work) I have 9 columns:
    (i) acct_number
    (ii) system
    (iii) source
    (iv) object
    (v) group
    (vi) code
    (vii) detail
    (viii) routing
    (ix) complexity

    In Table 2 (Errors) I have 9 Columns:
    (i) active_flag
    (ii) system
    (iii) source
    (iv) object
    (v) group
    (vi) code
    (vii) detail
    (viii) routing
    (ix) complexity
```

Therefore both tables have the same columns except that the Error table does not have the acct_number column and the Work table does not have the active_flag column.

I am attempting to match (join) the active_flag column from the Error table to the Work table based on a match from the other 8 columns.

The result I am looking would look like this: acct_number, active_flag (where each account number is showing whether or not the error associated is active or inactive).

Comment: Up to now, I have been using queries like:

Comment: what is the join condition?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl1
JOIN tbl2
  USING (
    acct_number,
    system,
    source,
    object,
    group,
    code,
    detail,
    routing,
    complexity
  );
```

But this is insanity. You should be reducing this to a sane primary key. Even if you're primary key is a natural key, this many columns is *highly* indicative of bad practice.

Comment: I am such a beginner. Thank you so much for such a quick response! I will look into your suggestion as this may save me tons of time in the future!!!

Comment: @AnonymousUser consider taping into your local resources and getting assistance learning SQL and RDBMs. You can do it, and you need to do it. =) Good luck.

Comment: I will =)!!! Once again, thank you so much. I am very interested in this field and just started getting into it within the month. I think its time for some learning courses!

Comment: @AnonymousUser I would connect locally before you do any of that. There are groups in every major city that would be glad to help you. Go make a friend. (Google <your_city> + meetup + topic) where topic is Linux, PostgreSQL, Database, or Data Management and the like.